# Data races detected while deleting QThreads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, valgrind, data-race

I am working on a multithread project and I am trying to detect thread inconsistency using helgrind (valgrind tool).

After closing the app I get multiples reports like this:

```
==50932== Possible data race during read of size 8 at 0x3413C718 by thread #26
==50932== Locks held: none
==50932==    at 0xB91ED11: QObjectPrivate::ConnectionData::removeConnection(QObjectPrivate::Connection*) (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.10)
==50932==    by 0xB92A4E2: QObject::~QObject() (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.10)\
==50932==    by 0x525E9F: classA::~classA() (classA.cpp:52)
==50932==    by 0x525EC3: classA::~classA() (classA.cpp:52)
==50932==    by 0xB922012: QObject::event(QEvent*) (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.10)
==50932==    by 0x9CC66D2: QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.10)
==50932==    by 0xB8F4E19: QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.10)
==50932==    by 0xB8F7F06: QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.10)
==50932==    by 0xB94EA36: ??? (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.10)
==50932==    by 0xCCA8D3A: g_main_context_dispatch (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==50932==    by 0xCCFE257: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==50932==    by 0xCCA63E2: g_main_context_iteration (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==50932==
==50932== This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #25
==50932== Locks held: none
==50932==    at 0xB91ED20: QObjectPrivate::ConnectionData::removeConnection(QObjectPrivate::Connection*) (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.10)
==50932==    by 0xB92A4E2: QObject::~QObject() (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.10)
==50932==    by 0x468CA9: IclassB::~IclassB() (IclassB.h:43)
==50932==    by 0x4646ED: classB::~classB() (classB.cpp:75)
==50932==    by 0x464711: classB::~classB() (classB.cpp:75)
==50932==    by 0xB922012: QObject::event(QEvent*) (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.10)
==50932==    by 0x9CC66D2: QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.10)
==50932==    by 0xB8F4E19: QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.10)
==50932==  Address 0x3413c718 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 88 alloc'd
==50932==    at 0x484AFF5: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:483)
==50932==    by 0xB9233E4: QObjectPrivate::connectImpl(QObject const*, int, QObject const*, void**, QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase*, Qt::ConnectionType, int const*, QMetaObject const*) (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.10)
==50932==    by 0xB923964: QObject::connectImpl(QObject const*, void**, QObject const*, void**, QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase*, Qt::ConnectionType, int const*, QMetaObject const*) (in /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.10)
==50932==    by 0x3E52AF: std::enable_if<QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::{lambda()#31}>::ArgumentCount==(-1), QMetaObject::Connection>::type QObject::connect<void> (QObject::*)(QObject*), MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::{lambda()#31}>(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<void> (QObject::*)(QObject*)>::Object const*, void (QObject::*)(QObject*), > QObject const*, MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::{lambda()#31}, > Qt::ConnectionType) (qobject.h:347)
==50932==    by 0x3D2149: MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*) (mainwindow.cpp:633)
==50932==    by 0x374017: main (main.cpp:199)
==50932==  Block was alloc'd by thread #1
==50932==
```

So I have 2 classes running in different threads and when I close the app it seems like they both access to `QObjectPrivate::ConnectionData::removeConnection()` and since this method is from the Qt framework itself it seems that the data races cannot be tackled.

`IclassB` Is the interface for `classB` so it has nothing implemented.

Both threads A and B access to their destructor which are:

```
classB::~classB()
{
    if (d != nullptr)
    {
        delete d->member;
        delete d;
    }
}
```

and

```
classA::~classA()
{
    if (d != nullptr)
    {
        if (d->mm->isActive())
            d->mm->stop();
        delete d;
    }

}
```

I cannot see anything weird with the destructors. I just wanna make sure that this dataraces is a false positive because I have a lot of this type.

Comment: Try `thread-sanitizer` for more info. Also, always make sure your threads have terminated (usually by `join`ing them) before terminating the program.

Comment: please include text as text. 
[Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: usually you should not delete QObjects manually in Qt, especially if they are connected to objects in other thread. QThreads also should be stopped before QApplication destructor call. It looks like you have broken parenting chain and memory smash somewher

Comment: Why `delete d->member` instead of having `d` delete the members on his own?

Comment: @JesperJuhl presumably that will need a tsan build of Qt

Comment: Why are you deleting the same object on two threads? I would say that classB is deleting something that it does not own.

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes, classB  has a private member names d, and its class is privateClassB. This class is instantiated inside classB.cpp and instead of using its destructor I delete inside classB destructor. I do not think that is the point of the problem.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Sure. And? Building Qt doesn't take that long.

Comment: @PaulFloyd it is not he same object, just has the same name

Comment: There is a very specific sequence of stuff, which is the right way to use threads in Qt. See and learn: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html

Comment: Don't use `delete`. Either use QObject parent, use `deleteLater()` slot (example behind above link) or use `std::unique_ptr`. There are no valid cases for using `delete` directly.

Comment: In Qt, QObject must be destructed in the right thread. Any QObjects with a particular thread affinity must either be pushed to other threads from that thread, or destructed in that thread, before the thread terminates. Again see previous link for example.